# Pass multiple arguments to WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm clearly not doing this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Essentially i am pulling nearby zip codes and city names to a search that is being done. i then want to use WP_Query to pull the WordPress post types matching those zip codes and city names. I'm not super familiar with WordPress, so it is highly likely i'm way off base on how to do this:

```
$url = "http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/OeAp3k78myEhBy0oqSlQSlUWOt6N7TjW8Tlbdtkz1YRCwS1WKmNDIHzwbFjizCeI/radius.json/" . $searchbox . "/100/km";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($response);

$post_type = 'location';  
$citysearcharray = array();
$zipsearcharray = array();

$searcharray = array();
foreach($json->zip_codes as $nearbyzip)
{

    $citysearcharray[] = array(
        'key'       => 'city',
        'value'     => $nearbyzip->city,
        'compare'   => '='
    );

    $zipsearcharray[] = array(
        'key'       => 'zip_code',
        'value'     => $nearbyzip->zip_code,
        'compare'   => '='
    );
}

            $args = array(
            'post_type'       => $post_type,
            'post_status'     => 'publish',
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
            'posts_per_page'  => 10,
            'meta_query'    => array(
                'relation'      => 'OR', 
            $citysearcharray,
            $zipsearcharray));

    $my_query = null; 
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $count=0;


        echo '<ul class="location">';
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
...
```

Amy i putting the $args together correctly?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach, instead of adding new full values to your arrays

```
$zipsearcharray
```

and

```
 $citysearcharray
```

have the value key as an array so:

`'value'     => array(array of cities)`

then change

```
compare => 'IN'
```

Comment: Like this?

 foreach($json->zip_codes as $nearbyzip)
 {
  $citysearcharray[] = array($nearbyzip->city);
  $zipsearcharray[] = array($nearbyzip->zip_code);
 }

 $args = array(
 'post_type'       => $post_type,
 'post_status'     => 'publish',
 'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
 'posts_per_page'  => 10,
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation'  => 'OR', 
 array(
   'key'  => 'city',
   'value'  => $citysearcharray,
   'compare' => 'IN'
  ),
 array(
   'key'  => 'zip_code',
   'value'  => $zipsearcharray,
   'compare' => 'IN'
  )));

Comment: I get: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /nas/content/staging/agemarkch/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1166

Comment: ah yes, it should be  $citysearcharray[] =  $nearbyzip->city; not  $citysearcharray[] = array( $nearbyzip->city );